# adding rewards system points android

Tags: java, android

In my app I have an option were users can watch videos, and earn points from watching them. (3 Points per video). The user would watch the entire video and then afterwards would receive his points. Now I am inexperienced on how to actually add this point system. If anyone has done anything like this, I'd love some insight. Thank you! Something like the picture below, where users can see the total amount of points they have accumulated.

[image]

Comment: Are you launching an intent to play the video elsewhere, have you embedded the video, or are you using your own media player?

Comment: @sam_c For starters I'm using Admob on the videos, But i dont know how to add a points system for when the video finally finishes.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a definitive answer for this because it doesn't seem like Admob provides you with any information on how long the video is. As far as the code is concerned it's random (as far as I can tell). My best suggestion, which you may have already thought of, would be to utilize the AdListener class. Call `.setAdListener(new AdListener() {...}` and use `onAdOpened()` and/or `onAdClosed()` in conjunction with some generic timer logic that says if you watch for this much time you get the points, obviously not optimal. I'm sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: @sam_c The thing is It dosn't have anything to do with the video ads, I generally just need a counter that gives 3 points after 30 seconds of when the ad was displayed

Comment: In that case you could make your timer in the `onAdOpened()` function. If it reaches 30 seconds before `onAdClosed()` is called you can add 3 points.

Comment: Alright thank you, @sam_c